# how to set part of circle as background in css

Tags: css, sass, css-shapes

I am trying to get part of circle as back ground

What I want :

[image]

Example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to get this by `border-radius` but it doesn't work always.

Here is what I tried:

```
a{
  min-width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 15px !important;

  // active/current navigation link
  &.active, &:hover{
     background-color: #e15669;
    &:before{
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      display: block;
      height: 60px;
      width: 30px;
      border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
      -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
      background: #e15669;
      top: 0;
      left: -30px;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    &:after {
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      display: block;
      height: 60px;
      width: 30px;
      border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
      -moz-border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
      background: #e15669;
      top: 0;
      right: -30px;
      z-index: -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you add the HTML & CSS to fiddle

Comment: What do you mean by not always works?

Comment: @ShlomiHaver I have to write css for each element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a radial gradient to color the background like so

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 2em;
  color: white;
  background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side, red, red 90%, transparent 90%);
}
```

```html
<a href="#1">RANDOM</a>

<a href="#2">RANDOM TEXT</a>

<a href="#3">TEXT</a
```

## Alternate solution

A positioned pseudo-element. This allows for transitioning the background easily.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 2em;
  color: white;
  position: relative; /* positioning context */
  overflow: hidden; /* required to clip circle */
}
a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute; /* doesn't affect other elements */
  top: 50%; /* set 50% down */
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* pull up 50% of own height */
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: green;
  padding-bottom: 100%; /* makes square */
  border-radius: 50%; /* round it off */
  z-index: -1;
  transition:background .35s ease;
}

 a:hover::before {
   background: blue;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#1">RANDOM</a>

<a href="#2">RANDOM TEXT</a>

<a href="#3">TEXT</a>
```

Comment: First solution is what I need, But how can I solve pixelated  border ?

Comment: That's the problem with border-radius and sub-pixel rendering..not sure there is a solution...at least not one I have found.

Comment: @NeosFox , i guess you mean with chrome, you may blur the gradient edges  or use a background image + background-size http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grdkRW

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```css
.a {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
text-align:center;
background-color: red;
line-height:100px;
border-top-left-radius: 100%50px;
border-top-right-radius: 100%50px;    
border-bottom-left-radius: 100%50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 100%50px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="a">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution based on your code

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
a.active:before, a:hover:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 200%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: tomato;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">hello mate</a>
<hr>
<a class="active" href="#">active status</a>
```

### Updated answer

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 80px;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
a.active:before,
a:hover:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px/30px;
  background: tomato;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">hello mate</a>
<hr>
<a class="active" href="#">active status</a>
```

Comment: Note this requires **known** sizes and is not dynamic,

Comment: @Paulie_D Could you elaborate your comment ?

Comment: Without the magic numbers in your padding etc, the background is not a circle - https://jsfiddle.net/6krmoofa/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D please have a look the updated answer. Let me know your comments please

Comment: See, you're still using magic numbers. Ideally the circle would be maintained regardless of the height / width of the text...without having to adjust the padding / radius etc every time.

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for the valid point, I will have look after work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119024/discussion-between-muhammed-athimannil-and-paulie-d).

Comment: @Paulie_D Your solution doesn't work when there is line break in the link

Comment: Why would there be a line break in the link?

Comment: @Paulie_D It is designer's choice

Comment: @Paulie_D of course there is `radius` variation in the blocks https://jsfiddle.net/fpdtqqkx/1/

Comment: Of course there is...that's the point...that's what the OP is after..it's shown in the image in the question.

Comment: @Paulie_D Therefore we need to find better solution for that 